# How can I config my Mac to don't scape characters when I copy and paste some text on the console?

Tags: console

Is there anyway to config my Mac to don't scape characters when I copy and paste some text on the console? Could anybody help me? It is driving me crazy to erase all \ characters inserted after a simple copy and paste on the console.

Many thanks,
Thiago

Comment: Do you mean "Escape"? Because scape is not a word.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean escape.

Comment: The OP mentioned backslashes, so I assume they're talking about the escaping (which should probably be called "quoting") performed by **Edit > Paste Escaped Text**, in which case the answer is to use the normal **Paste** command instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about pasting into windows of the *Terminal* application (which is not the same as *Console* application; neither of which are the same as the actual “console”), then you can uncheck the **Escape non-ASCII input** option in the “settings set” that you are using.

With *Terminal* active, open the preferences: Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or select the **Terminal** > **Preferences…** menu item.

1. Click the **Settings** icon in the tool bar of the preferences window.
2. From the list on the left side of the preferences window,
   select the “settings set” that you want to modify.

   The settings set of the previously active *Terminal* window will be initially selected.
3. Click the **Advanced** tab.
4. Uncheck the **Escape non-ASCII input** checkbox.

[image: screenshot of Terminal Preferences window with mouse cursor on “Escape non-ASCII input” checkbox and numbered red arrows indicating steps to access the checkbox]

Comment: “Escape non-ASCII input” does not perform backslash escaping like **Paste Escaped Text**. “Escape non-ASCII input” prefixes each non-ASCII character with a Control-V. In Bash and probably other shells, this “quotes” control characters, for example, so they aren’t interpreted as commands.